# pandas groupby followed by resample work differently with datetime in index and datetime in different column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

// The comments have made me realize that this is actually a far broader question about how the `on` keyword works in `.reshape`. I left the old question below for reference, but I think the question is much broader.

Here's a reproducible example; I would expect the first two statements to give the same results, and the second two statements to give the same results. They don't.

```
get_df = lambda : pd.DataFrame( {'DATETIME' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01 11:25:00', '2018-01-01 11:50:00', '2018-01-03 10:30:00'
                                                    , '2018-01-04 10:25:00']*2),
                                 'GROUP'    : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                                 'FILTER'   : [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True],
                                 'X'        : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]} )

df = get_df()
df = df.set_index('DATETIME')
df.groupby('GROUP').resample('D').X.sum()
# Returns
# -------
# GROUP  DATETIME  
# A      2018-01-01     3
#        2018-01-02     0
#        2018-01-03     3
#        2018-01-04     4
# B      2018-01-01    11
#        2018-01-02     0
#        2018-01-03     7
#        2018-01-04     8
# Name: X, dtype: int64

df = get_df()
df.groupby('GROUP').resample('D', on = 'DATETIME').X.sum()
# Returns
# -------
# GROUP  DATETIME  
# A      2018-01-01    10
# B      2018-01-03    11
#        2018-01-04    15
# Name: X, dtype: int64

df = get_df()
df = df.set_index('DATETIME')
df[df.FILTER].groupby('GROUP').resample('D').X.sum()
# Returns
# -------
# GROUP  DATETIME  
# A      2018-01-01    3
#        2018-01-02    0
#        2018-01-03    3
#        2018-01-04    4
# B      2018-01-03    7
#        2018-01-04    8
# Name: X, dtype: int64

df = get_df()
df[df.FILTER].groupby('GROUP').resample('D', on = 'DATETIME').X.sum()
# Error
# -----
#    IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for size 6
```

Any thoughts?

---

***Original question***

I'm trying to do a groupby followed by a re-sample in pandas. This works if the date is in the df's index, but NOT if it is in a column, and I supply the "on" keyword in the re-sample.

Python 3.7.1 and Pandas 0.24.2

Set up the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'DATETIME' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01 11:25:00', '2018-01-01 11:50:00', '2018-01-03 10:30:00'
                                                   , '2018-01-04 10:25:00', '2018-01-03 10:30:00', '2018-01-04 10:25:00']),
                    'GROUP'    : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                    'X'        : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]} )
```

Then run this:

```
df[df.GROUP == 'B'].groupby('GROUP').resample('D', on = 'DATETIME').X.sum()
```

And I get this error: `IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for size 2`

If, however, I first index by the date:

```
df = df.set_index('DATETIME')
df[df.GROUP == 'B'].groupby('GROUP').resample('D').X.sum()
```

It works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you using both filter and groupby, any sigificance

Comment: @NagaKiran actually if you remove the filter `[df.GROUP == 'B']`, both methods give a result, but the results are not the same while I think they should be

Comment: @NagaKiran , in my original example, I was filtering on another column, not on the group-by column. Data in the question changed to reflect that. Still same problem

Comment: @Ben.T : wow, you're right! It's a bigger problem than I thought. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "apply" on a custum function and let pandas adapt itself to the output.

```
def my_func(grouped):
  my_sum = grouped.resample('D', on = 'DATETIME').X.sum()
  return my_sum
```

Now call this function on your groupby object:

```
df[df.GROUP == 'B'].groupby("GROUP").apply(my_func)
```

You get:

```
#Output
    DATETIME    2018-01-03 00:00:00     2018-01-04 00:00:00
GROUP       
  B                        5                     6
```

What you did is ambiguous: pandas expects a series of 2 elements because group B has 2 elements but you are trying to obtain a dataframe like above.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that this works, but we're talking about a dataframe with 300M rows. `.apply` will be super-slow. I want to use more native vectorized Pandas functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with my resampling.  You have to run the following sequence of setting and reseting the index in order to make the index error go away:

```
df = df.set_index('order_date')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

> This line of code below will return an error if you do not run code above

```
df.groupby('Ship To #').resample('MS', on='order_date').product.sum()
```

hope it works.